# Renaming log files with Python using wildcard and datetime

Tags: python, file, logging

I was searching today for options to manipulate some log files, after executing actions on them, and I found that Python has the os.rename resource, after importing the os module, but I have some regex doubts..

Tried to fit a wildcard "*****" on my file names, but Python seems not to understand it.

My file names are:

Application_2021-08-06_hostname_[**PID**].log

Currently I'm asking Python to read these application files, and search for defined words/phrases such as "User has logged in", "User disconnected" and etc. And he does well. I'm using datetime module so Python will always read the current files only.

But what I'm trying to do now, is to change the name of the file, after Python read it and execute something. So when he find "Today's sessions are done", he will change the name of the file to:

Application_06-08-2021_hostname_[**PID**].log

Because it will be easier for manipulating later..

Considering that [**PID**] will always change, this is the part that I wanted to set the wildcard, because it can be 56, 142, 3356, 74567 or anything.

Using the os.rename module, I've got some errors. What do you suggest?

**Code**:

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime

path = '/users/application/logs'

file_name = 'Application_%s_hostname_'% datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
new_file_name = 'Application_%s_hostname_'% datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

os.rename(file_name, new_file_name)
```

The error is:

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: You are not using the full path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `glob` which allows for wildcards:

```
import glob, os
from datetime import datetime
current_date = datetime.now()
path = '/users/application/logs'
# note the use of * as wild card
filename ='Application_%s_hostname_*'% current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
full_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
replace_file = glob.glob(full_path)[0]  # will return a list so take first element
# or loop to get all files
new_name = replace_file.replace(  current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),  current_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') )
os.rename(replace_file, new_name)
```